How do I propagate a MUI theme from my App to a 3rd party library of customized MUI components?
I'm creating a library of customized MUI components that will be reused by more than one app. I want the library of components to reflect the theme that is applied to the App consuming the library.
Simple example library containing a MUI table in a repo here:
https://github.com/jantal80/jaa-component-library
which I published to npm here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jaa-my-component-library
Now I create a simple app using vite npm create vite@latest:
https://github.com/jantal80/jaa-app
...using both a MUI table directly, as well as the "JaaTable" imported from jaa-my-component-library. I wrap the App with a ThemeProvider, and that theme gets applied to the MUI table imported to the App, but does not get applied to the "JaaTable"
I have @mui/material as a peerDependency in my package.json of the library.
How can I get the theme to propagate from the App to the library components?? I have used other third party libraries that at least respond to dark/light mode theme, so it seems this is possible, but I have not found a way to do it. I've found somewhat similar stackoverflow questions but not one that answers it for me.
TIA!
theme not changing gif

Have you tried getting the theme using useTheme hook from @mui/material in jaa-component-library/src/App.tsx? You could log it to the console to see if it's synced with the theme of jaa-app. If the theme is synced, try wrapping the jaa-component-library JSX elements in App.tsx with a <ThemeProvider>

thanks for the response. I suppose I made a mistake leaving the vite generated App.tsx etc. inside of jaa-component-library as that could cause confusion here.  I should remove that code. The themeProvider is on the App in jaa-app, I'm trying to make sure that same theme makes its way to the library components. I tried the suggested useTheme and used that theme to wrap my JaaTable component, but no change in behavior

It turns out my code was fine, it was the package/vite/tsconfig settings.
I found a library (mui-color-input) that used vite and also responded appropriately to dark/light theme settings. Then I compared that line by line with what I had, and made changes accordingly. I believe there was still a dependency conflict even though I had @mui in the peer dependencies. The index.d.ts was also no getting written to dist.
